Selling Employee Stock Options
At my previous employer, I received company stock through an Employee Stock Purchase Plan, at a discount from the price at the time. I kept all the paperwork for the stock purchases. My wife also had an ESPP from a different employer, but I can’t find the paperwork for them.
I’m ready to retire, and want to sell some of the stock. Would the holder of the stock shares (ComputerShare) know what each share cost, and if there was a discount? What happens when you sell stock if you don’t know what the price and discount were, if you lost that paperwork?

If you know the date the shares were acquired, there are web sites that can provide historical stock prices. This won't include the discount, but ComputerShare might know that.

This depends on when and how the shares were acquired. They might not. Brokers are only required to track basis for covered securities (ESPP shares are usually covered), but they're not required to track adjustments - that's on you (in case there are any wash sales, for example). Tracking basis for covered securities is a (relatively) new regulation starting from 2011 and on. So if your position is older it could very well be that the brokers don't have any information about how much you paid.
You'll need to try and recover the missing information by checking the W2 for that year (ESPP purchase may be reported in box 14), or the detailed payslips for that year. You may also try and reach out to the company and see if they can recover the missing paperwork. If you cannot find any documentation whatsoever to establish basis, you may end up paying capital gains tax on the entire proceeds. You cannot just "guess" how much you paid.

Ouch! Thanks for the helpful answer.
